# Pine-script: Getting the last close value as a constant

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the integer value of the close of the previous bar as a constant.

Using close[1] would return a series[float], and I require this to be a constant integer.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. `Constant` values known at the compile time, while data of the `close` is not (serial values).
You can describe what application you need constant for, and maybe there is workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The current program I am working on requires the strategy to run every 4hours on a 15minute chart. I planned to use the above method to fetch the 4hr data every 4hrs. Unfortunately using a 4hr resolution by itself returns data every 15minutes (base resolution).